# Console.ReadKey(); is throwing an exception

Tags: c#

I am completely new to programming, just saying. `Console.ReadKey();` is throwing an exception with the message 'System.InvalidOperationException'. I've been browsing in the site and didn't found this exact problem. How can I solve this?

Sidenote: I have .Net Core installed.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It would be very helpful to include the full error message that's in the screenshot, but as text in the question. The text of the message makes it much clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if STDIN is redirected, use `Console.IsInputRedirected` (`public static bool IsInputRedirected { get; }`)